# socket.timeout; Explanation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, timeout

I am building a port scanning program ((irrelevant to the question, just explaining the background)), and I know the IP of the host, but not what ports are open. Hence, the scan.

It is in the early stages of development, so the error handling is bad,  but not bad enough to make why Python does this explainable.

It tries to connect to, say, `123.456.7.8, 1`. Obviously it's a ridiculous port to be open, so it throws an error. The error is `No Route to Host` or the such, right? Wrong! It is instead `Operation Timed Out!`.

Okay, let's increase the timeout in case my calculations were incorrect.

.
..
...
....All that did was rinse and repeat!

About 20 minutes later, the timeout is at 20 seconds, and it *still* is timing out. Really? Why does python raise a `timed out` error though, instead of `No route to host!` or similar?

I ***need*** to distinguish between time outs and connection failures, because there *is* a difference between late and nowhere. This prevents me from doing so, creating an infinite loop of hurry up and  wait.

Whatever shall I do? Wherever shall I go?

Comment: Wherever shall I go? SO! Whatever shall I do? Post a cut down version of your code that demonstrates the problem! ;)

Comment: This isn't a MyCode Problem, this is a PyCode Problem! ;)

Comment: If it is a python problem then you will have to post a bug fix request. If, however, it is a problem with your code, then you should create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You may well find that in the process, you find your own resolution to the problem.

Comment: Alright. Let's try this again.

It's not a bug anywhere. It's a problem. I was asking why it does that, and if there's a solution. That's how SO works, isn't it?

Comment: Without being able to see what you are attempting to do and how you are doing it, you are asking us to guess what the problem is. An important principle of SO is that if you have a question you need to provide the people reading your question, with, minimally, the code that is causing the problem and preferably a "minimal, complete and verifiable example". That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0):

Python `socket` module is a thin wrapper around your platform's socket API. The issue is unrelated to Python.

It is not necessary that you get `No Route to Host` error. Moreover it is common that a firewall just drops received packets (for a filtered port) that may manifest as a timeout error in your code. See [Drop vs. Reject](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/network/drop-vs-reject) (ignore the conclusion but read the explanation of what is happening).

To workaround, make multiple concurrent connections and set a fixed timeout or use raw-sockets and send the packets yourself (you could [use `scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html), to investigate the behavior).